# calling diploid SNVs from long reads

Tags: vcf, snp, variant-calling, long-reads, pacbio

I'd like to call diploid SNV variants from long-reads data (~80SMRTcells PacBio).

I have generated a draft reference genome for an indivudual from a heterozygous (~4%) species ([Canu](https://github.com/marbl/canu)+[Haplomerger2](https://github.com/mapleforest/HaploMerger2)).

I can use this reference for some applications:

- RNAseq mapping;
- functional annotation;
- duplicate detection;
- synteny analysis

but not others:

- analysis of compound heterozygotes;
- allele-specific expression;
- variant linkage

This is mainly why I need phasing. FYI, I tried [Falcon + FalconUnzip](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/FALCON/wiki/FALCON-FALCON-Unzip-%22For-Phased-Diploid-Genome-Assembly-with-Single-Molecule-Real-Time-Sequencing%22) too, but the daligner phase was just taking too much time/resources and I need to find a strategy to make it work in reasonable time (working on it).

Meanwhile, for phasing, It was suggested to use [HapCUT2](https://github.com/vibansal/HapCUT2/blob/master/README.md) - from Canu's FAQ

> (1) "Avoid collapsing the genome" in Canu to get raw diploid assembly as complete & separate as possible (2) HaploMerger2 to get high-quality reference and alternative haploid assemblies (3) HapCUT2 or other phasing tools to get the high-quality haplotype assembly based on the reference haploid assembly.

However, HapCUT2 requires the input of a diploid SNV file. Which [could be done](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/converting-a-bam-file-into-vcf/4022#4022) if I had short-reads data, but yet haven't found a method for doing so with in my hands just long-reads data.

Strategies I tried to get the SNVs:

- [marginPhase](https://github.com/benedictpaten/marginPhase) : [method paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/04/12/293944)

  - but I had a [issue](https://github.com/benedictpaten/marginPhase/issues/12) in running it
- [Clairvoyante](https://github.com/aquaskyline/Clairvoyante) : [method paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/04/28/310458)

  - but I currently don't have access to suitable GPU machines to build the model - and I can't use the models provided by the authors because my organism is too different from human

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: At 4% heterozygosity, falcon-unzip is probably the best hope. Trio binning would be better but you don't have the right data.

Comment: @user172818 is it possible in your knowledge to run Falcon-Unzip on non-Falcon output? From [here](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/FALCON_unzip/issues/100) it looks like it's a no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the longshot tool (https://github.com/pjedge/longshot) developed for calling variants in diploid genomes from long read data.

Answer (score 2):

You could try aligning your reads to the draft reference genome with for example `minimap2` and calling variants with `freebayes`. It appears there is a protocol for long reads: https://github.com/ekg/freebayes#re-genotyping-known-variants-and-calling-long-haplotypes

Disclaimer: I have not run `freebayes` myself, and it may be that this is a terrible idea. I would expect that calling SNVs (Single-nucleotide variants) from PacBio reads is very challenging.  However, with enough coverage, I think it could be possible.